# Undoing while mouse cursor is in Viewport undoes code input in Text Editor instead of actions in Viewport

Tags: python, scripting

When I run a script that edits the mesh in some way and don’t like how it turns out, I move the mouse cursor to the viewport and hit ctrl + Z and

1. The first to be undone is the last input in the Text Editor, usually the line of code right before execution
2. After the line is completely undone, the results of that script run is then undone from the viewport

Is there a way to undo the results of the last execution of script without undoing the text input in the Text Editor?

Comment: AFAIK the undo stack is a continuous list of undo steps so you can't really pick and choose a particular editor to undo actions from. You may script a custom implementation of undo but I would expect it to be buggy if not done well. Undo tends to mess up the pointers location in memory

Comment: @Gorgious i was wondering if I was doing it wrong because the order of these are 1. Text Editor input 2. Script execution 3. Results in Viewport, so that 3 should be on top of the “undo stack” you mentioned

Comment: Oh right sorry I didn't understand your problem. What exactly does your script do ?

Comment: The script edits the coordinates of the vertices on the mesh in edit mode somewhat. I think I figured out a way tho - the solution is that every time before I run a script I do an empty action in the view port (select or deselect). Then if I undo after the script execution it undoes the execution first